# Change pixel colors between two different colors

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, pixel

I have this image:

[image]

And I would like to change the group of pixels(greem colour) between or in contact with red and yellow pixels, by red color, this way:

[image]

Sorry, I don't have any one code, because I don't know how to start this, and I did not find an approach to do this. I think a similar logic related to `PIL`, like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('image.png')
data = np.array(im)

r1, g1, b1 = 255, 255, 255 # Original value
r2, g2, b2 = 0, 0, 0 # Value that we want to replace it with

red, green, blue = data[:,:,0], data[:,:,1], data[:,:,2]
mask = (red == r1) & (green == g1) & (blue == b1)
data[:,:,:3][mask] = [r2, g2, b2]

im = Image.fromarray(data)
```

But with a condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may start the solution by using [cv2.floodFill](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaf1f55a048f8a45bc3383586e80b1f0d0) method.

Main stages:

- Fill the lower part with black using `floodFill` (assume only yellow and green pixels).
- Fill the top part with black using `floodFill` (assume only red and green pixels).
- Find pixels where both top and bottom are zeros (black).
- Replace the pixels that are both black with red color.

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('red_yellow_green.jpg')

cols, rows = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]

red = img[0, 0, :].tolist() # Get the red color from the top left corner

# Make the green a "true green"
img2 = img.copy()
green_ch = img2[:, :, 1]
green_ch[green_ch > 100] = 255

# Fill the lower part with black (assume only yellow and green pixels)
bot_black = img2
cv2.floodFill(bot_black, None, seedPoint=(rows-1, cols-1), newVal=(0, 0, 0), loDiff=(255, 20, 255), upDiff=(255, 20, 255))

# Fill the top part with black (assume only red and green pixels)
top_black = img.copy()
cv2.floodFill(top_black, None, seedPoint=(0, 0), newVal=(0, 0, 0), loDiff=(50, 255, 50), upDiff=(50, 255, 50))

# Find pixels where both top and bottom are zeros
both_black = np.logical_and(np.all(bot_black[:, :, 0:3] == (0, 0, 0), 2), np.all(top_black[:, :, 0:3] == (0, 0, 0), 2))

# Convert to uint8 and dilate (this part is just for aesthetics).
both_black = both_black.astype(np.uint8)*255
both_black = cv2.dilate(both_black, np.ones((5,5)))

# Replace the pixels that are both black with red color
img[both_black == 255] = red

# Show images for testing:
cv2.imshow('bot_black', bot_black)
cv2.imshow('top_black', top_black)
cv2.imshow('both_black', both_black)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Results:

`bot_black`:
[image]

`top_black`:
[image]

`both_black`:
[image]

`img`:
[image]

---

The above solution is not the most general solution.
There is also an option to find all the green contours, create a mask of the contours perimeter, and analyze the colors of the perimeter of each contour (and fill contours with mixed perimeter colors with red color).

Comment: Perfect, worked well. But a doubt, I did not understand the part of a 'true green'. For example, if i want to use an example with white color or another colour rather than green?

Comment: The solution is not a general solution. The values of `loDiff` and `upDiff` are selected for filling both yellow and green, and then both red and green. I had to make some assumptions, and I assumed the image is divided top and bottom, and the colors are red yellow and green. The suggestion below the image is more general, but more complicated. You may start by two `floodFill` on the same image that keeps only the green areas, then find contours, draw the contours on a black background, dilate, keep only the outer part, use it as a mask (perimeter around greens), analyze the perimeter...

Comment: Sorry to disturb you. I think i don't give the best example. Can I post another image in my question like an aditional attachment? I think wiil better,

Comment: Is it going to make my answer looks bad? You may post it in a comment, or ask a followed question. I can't stop you from editing your question, but I am not sure I am going to have a solution.